# Proof of an expected value for a continuous random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

One more question I've been having trouble with, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

The question is:

For any positive continuous random variable $X$ with pdf $ f_X(x)$, show that
$E\left(\frac{1}{X^2}\right) \geq \left[E\left(\frac{1}{X}\right)\right]^2$.

Comment: Use [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) on the map $\varphi(u) =  u^2$.

Comment: Define $\frac 1 X=Y$ (for clarity) and expand/rearrange $E(((Y-E(Y))^2)\ge 0$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 that's outside the realm of anything I've learned so far in probability theory, would you know of a different way?

Comment: You should pick it up, it's super useful, and not that hard to figure out (at least in the discrete case). Any way, what A.S. suggests seems fine. You should note that the inequality is equivalent to saying that the variance is positive.

Comment: Will do, thanks to both of you!

Comment: One could use the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, or Jensen's Inequality, but these would be fancier tools.  The suggestion given is very good. Note that the expectations may not exist.